# angularjs ng-repeat start with empty

Tags: angularjs

In angular js first value should be emty

```
<thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in reports">
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th ng-if="$parent.$index==0" ng-repeat="data in value">{{$index+1}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

How to add first value as empty loop start from 2nd `<th>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$first`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview) to check whether current item is the first one in the collection:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.reports = {
      first: 1,
      second: 2
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in reports">
        <th ng-if="$first">&nbsp;</th>
        <th ng-if="!$first">{{key}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```